# Can an automated JavaScript Documentation Tool Parse a Function Literal as a function?

Tags: javascript, documentation, currying

I've not yet found a JavaScript documentation tool that properly outputs function expressions as functions.

E.g.:

```
/**
* @param a {number}
* @param b {number}
* @returns {number}
*/
export const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
```

...gets documented as a variable in jsdoc and esdoc, which of course it is, but it also happens to be a variable referencing a function. I could of course write it thus:

```
/**
* @param a {number}
* @param b {number}
* @returns {number}
*/
export function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

...but that makes it awkward to export as a curried function, using something like Ramda's `curry`. E.g.:

```
import {curry} from "ramda";

export const add = curry((a, b) => a + b);
```

Is it particularly hard for a tool to understand the expression to be a function, or is there an existing tool out there that I am missing?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you could create JSDoc for things that don't exist in order to re-use it. So you can say something like `@return SomeFunctionType` and it will replace `SomeFunctionType` with its JSDoc declaration that doesn't map to a real thing. Maybe that's more like what you want. I'll have to find where I've seen that.

Comment: OK, looking at the documentation I can't see what I'm talking about. I've either hallucinated that, or it is a different documentation tool. I'm blanking out on what other JS documentation tools I've ever really looked at. JSDoc apparently [supports plugins](https://jsdoc.app/about-plugins.html), so I'm not sure if 1. that's a solution at all 2. is it a suitable solution here.

Comment: For even further information, there is an [open issue on JSDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1286) that asks for support for currying. It was first reported in October 2016, so...it's been a while. Skimming through the replies there, some people seem to have found ways to make it work but I didn't look too deeply into it.

Comment: I hope I'm not getting too annoying with comments. I looked at what Ramda does, and it does use JSDoc. [See the source of `add`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/add.js) and [this is what it produces](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#add). I am unsure how they actually produce the documentation, though - I tried to look at the build scripts but I don't see it. Either I'm missing it or it's not in the repo.